# Prerequisites to study Laplace Transform completely?

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy

Hello to all the professors who read this. I'm an electrical engineering undergrad student. I wanted to ask for advice on what I should learn beforehand to fully grasp the Laplace transform. I also want to know what the prerequisites for Fourier Analysis/ Fourier Series/ Fourier Transform and the prerequisites to work through "Trigonometric Series" by Zygmund. would be, now that I'm asking this question.

Any book titles are warmly welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Educators! My first piece of advice would be to talk to the instructors who teach those topics. For instance, the Laplace transform can be studied at various levels. When I teach it in a differential equations course, the main prerequisites are calculus, complex numbers and exposure to differential equations from earlier in the course. It is used mainly as a tool. However, if you want to understand it in more depth. you would probably want to take a course in complex analysis/variables first. I recommend you edit your question to clarify what level you want to reach.

Comment: *the prerequisites to work through "Trigonometric Series" by Zygmund* --- This is primarily a reference work, and I suspect very few people now alive have completely worked through it. ("Very few" meaning at most a few dozen, and this upper bound is probably very generous.)

Comment: @JW Good piece of advice. I just wanted a general direction in which to proceed before learning it. That was good enough. I will study differential equations over my winter break intensively through a few books.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I see. What would you say would be the prerequisites to at least start?

Comment: For a prerequisite to Zygmund's treatise, probably complex analysis covering at least the first half of Ahlfors's book or Conway's book, and everything (except possibly Chapters 10 and 11) in [**Measure and Integral**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824764994) by Wheeden/Zygmund might be enough, and a huge amount to time (probably several years). However, Zygmund's trig. series treatise only goes up to 1959 (latest revised edition), so it's definitely now more of a reference work than something a future harmonic analysis researcher would be advised to spend several years working through.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thanks a lot!

Comment: With respect to the books, it's worth taking a look at [Dyke's](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Wuq7BAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Dyke+laplace&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiepPm7rJTsAhUho1kKHe8vCjgQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=Dyke%20laplace&f=false) and [Schiff's](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=N_jZBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Schiff+laplace&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF4ISurJTsAhUQw1kKHfumAcYQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=Schiff%20laplace&f=false) titles.

Comment: @Pedro: Those are much better given the OP's statement *I'm an electrical engineering undergrad student*. In fact, given this background and for Laplace transforms only, I'd recommend starting with the [Schaum's Outline](https://www.amazon.com//dp/007060231X), and if the OP really wants something **beyond** what you've offered, there's [Widder's 1941 book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/048647755X) (recently reprinted by Dover) that is somewhat akin to Zygmund's treatise in sophistication and written back in roughly the same era.

Comment: @Pedro Thanks a lot for the suggestions!